# Python Pandas: DataFrame filter negative values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I was wondering how I can remove all indexes that containing negative values inside their column. I am using Pandas `DataFrames`.

[Documentation Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Format:

**Myid** - **valuecol1** - **valuecol2** - **valuecol3** -... **valuecol30**

So my `DataFrame` is called `data`

I know how to do this for 1 column:

```
data2 = data.index[data['valuecol1'] > 0]
data3 = data.ix[data3]
```

So I only get the ids where `valuecol1 > 0`, how can I do some kind of `and` statement?

`valuecol1 && valuecol2 && valuecol3 && ... && valuecol30 > 0` ?

Comment: what if I want to get the names list of student who have negative score.

Comment: @NipulSindwani Try `df[df["score"] < 0]["name"]` but in general, please post a new question if you have a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could loop over the column names

```
for cols in data.columns.tolist()[1:]:
    data = data.ix[data[cols] > 0]
```

Answer (score 45):

You can use `all` to check an entire row or column is True:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
          0         1         2
0 -1.003735  0.792479  0.787538
1 -2.056750 -1.508980  0.676378
2  1.355528  0.307063  0.369505
3  1.201093  0.994041 -1.169323
4 -0.305359  0.044360 -0.085346
5 -0.684149 -0.482129 -0.598155
6  1.795011  1.231198 -0.465683
7 -0.632216 -0.075575  0.812735
8 -0.479523 -1.900072 -0.966430
9 -1.441645 -1.189408  1.338681

In [13]: (df > 0).all(1)
Out[13]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

In [14]: df[(df > 0).all(1)]
Out[14]:
          0         1         2
2  1.355528  0.307063  0.369505
```

If you only want to look at a subset of the columns, e.g.`[0, 1]`:

```
In [15]: df[(df[[0, 1]] > 0).all(1)]
Out[15]:
          0         1         2
2  1.355528  0.307063  0.369505
3  1.201093  0.994041 -1.169323
6  1.795011  1.231198 -0.465683
```

Answer (score 6):

To use and statements inside a data-frame you just have to use a single & character and separate each condition with parenthesis.

For example:

```
data = data[(data['col1']>0) & (data['valuecol2']>0) & (data['valuecol3']>0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the values of an adjacent group of columns, for example from the second to the tenth:

```
df[(df.ix[:,2:10] > 0).all(1)]
```

You can also use a range

```
df[(df.ix[:,range(1,10,3)] > 0).all(1)]
```

and an own list of indices

```
mylist=[1,2,4,8]
df[(df.ix[:, mylist] > 0).all(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/data.csv')
df_new = df[(df['Quantity'] < 0)]
df_new
df_new['Quantity1'] = df.Quantity
df_new.shape
```