# Filter negative values from a pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, filter, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with >40 columns with mixed values. How can I select only positive values from all columns at once & filter out negative ones? I visited [[Python Pandas: DataFrame filter negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214941/python-pandas-dataframe-filter-negative-values]) but none of the solutions are working. I would like to fit Naive Bayes in pyspark where one of the assumptions are all the features have to be positive. How can I prepare data for the same by selecting only positive values from my features?

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have a dataframe like this

```
data = [(0,-1,3,4,5, 'a'), (0,-1,3,-4,5, 'b'), (5,1,3,4,5, 'c'), 
        (10,1,13,14,5,'a'),(7,1,3,4,2,'b'), (0,1,23,4,-5,'c')]
df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['f1', 'f2','f3','f4', 'f5', 'class'])
```

use a `VectorAssembler` to assemble all the columns in a vector.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

transformer = VectorAssembler(inputCols =['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5'], outputCol='features')
df2 = transformer.transform(df)
```

Now, filter the dataframe using a udf

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
foo = udf(lambda x: not np.any(np.array(x)<0), BooleanType())
df2.drop('f1','f2','f3','f4','f5').filter(foo('features')).show()
```

result

```
+-----+--------------------+
|class|            features|
+-----+--------------------+
|    c|[5.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,...|
|    a|[10.0,1.0,13.0,14...|
|    b|[7.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Not working & failing with multiple errors. I have 4 categorical columns I am encoding them. transformer.transform() is not working for that. BooleanType() is not also defined.

Comment: I have added the import statement for the booleantype. This logic will work only if you have numerical predictors. Once you encode the categorical types it will work.

Comment: You should post a sample of your data.